# R Plotly legend duplicates when using lines and markers

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the following multiple lines plotly plot:

```
plt <- plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y = ~COUNT, color = ~Action, connectgaps = TRUE, 
                mode = "lines+markers", type = 'scatter', text = line_text) %>% add_lines() %>% 
                layout(showlegend = T)
```

The problem I face is that the legend shows duplicate values for both lines and markers.
[image]
Is there a way to remove those duplicates? For example, I don't want to see "Daily avg" twice in the legend.
Many thanks

Comment: Can you add your `df` or some other way of getting a [MCVE]?

Comment: Why do you `add_lines` if you already have `lines+markers`?

Comment: Oh you're right. I think I was using a premade plot template and I didn't fully understand the meaning of add_lines. Thank you Maximilian